# Magento event observer for bulk import for products

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

Is there any event for "bulk import of products/customers"?

I intend to make a module for my vendors to upload their product information in xml/csv through the backend. When they upload, I need to update my Solr records.

Thanx

Comment: What is "bulk import of products/customers"? Do you mean System -> Import/Export tool?

Comment: yes... i need a way of caching this "import/export" tool at the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::saveRow() as:
1> in config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
...
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <!-- Override Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product -->
                <convert_adapter_product>MagePsycho_Productimport_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product</convert_adapter_product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
...
    </models>
</global>
```

2> create class file as

```
class MagePsycho_Productimport_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
{    
    public function saveRow(array $importData)
    {
      parent::saveRow($importData);
      //do your extra stuffs here..
    }
}
```

Note: This is just an idea, you need to develop full working module by yourself.

Thanks
Regards
MagePsycho

Comment: Thank you MagePsycho. This idea worked. Though I had to override other few Models as well. :)