# Magento Dataflow (Advanced) Profile, default values

Tags: magento, csv, import, dataflow

I want to create an import from a CSV but i can't modify the CSV file.
So i need to define default values for a couple required fields in Magento (like "type" ( > Simple Product ) etc.

I'm looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7319214/2252078 to make a custom Adapter and that inject the missing required values in the array before saving.

But i already get an error that says:

```
Method "parse" not defined in adapter spaanproductions_basics/convert_adapter_product
```

So i can't even begin with my custom code.

Maybe someone has a beter idea how to create some default values, or how to fix this issue.

Magento version: 1.9.1.1

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards,
Sonny

Comment: Could you provide us with the PHP code of your class? 

class Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product extends Mage_Eav_Model_Convert_Adapter_Entity and has the function Parse directly in it (without any parent calls)

Comment: File: app/code/local/Spaanproductions/Basics/Model/Covert/Adapter/Product.php:
http://pastebin.com/D9UKFeFj

The Dataflow Profile (advanced) used:
http://pastebin.com/WgcZy4cC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is, your code does seem to be valid. You could try http://pastebin.com/vxewc0Zt . OR temporarily rename your app/code/local/Spaanproductions/Basics/Model/Covert/Adapter/Product.php to verify wetter the right class is actually being loaded although I highly doubt that's the problem

-- Edit (See comments) --
try changing spaanproductions_basics/convert_adapter_product to basics/convert_adapter_product your models are defined under basics, not under spaanproductions"

Comment: I have tried the pasted code, it's not working than.

If i rename my adapter I still get the same error. So it looks like it's not loading the right class? Hmmm, something wrong in my config.xml ?
http://pastebin.com/zWSZtryL

Comment: Small warning, I never work with the build in dataflow but! your config.xml seems to be fine. Based on http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/customizing-magento-dataflow-import-of-custom-data and http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-dataflow-data-exchange-made-flexible-part-1 I do notice that <action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map"> has a map, your <action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse"> has one which doesn't seem to be the way to go. What happens when you remove the adapter > spaanproductions_basics/convert_adapter_product line?

Comment: If i remove that like i get an error:  `Please declare "adapter" and "method" nodes first.` 

If i change it to:    `<var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_product</var>` it runs, but i get the error `Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"`

Thats why i want a custom adapter ;-)

Comment: I just noticed in my log that Magento is looking for `Mage/Spaanproductions/Basics/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php`

Comment: So that means your package isn't know in Magento itself, you could check you app/etc/modules/Foo_Bar.xml, permissions and verify this in the admin->config->system->advanced (if I remember correctly) of the options at the bottom which shows all the modules/extensions that have been loaded

Comment: The module is visible in Magento system > advanced. I have defined the model in the config.xml. Do i need to define the adapter in the confix.xml ?

Comment: Ahhh bingo! try changing <var name="adapter">spaanproductions_basics/convert_adapter_product</var> to <var name="adapter">basics/convert_adapter_product</var> your models are defined under basics, not under spaanproductions

Comment: Nice ! Tnx, that was it!

Comment: Please mark this as answered so the question will be closed

Answer (score 0):

At the first you have to export products as a csv file to catch the structure and then modify that as you need.

Take a look at this answer, it could be useful:

[Update Magento products with multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486035/update-magento-products-with-multiple-images/31500329#31500329)

Comment: I'm asuming that you mean that I need to modify my CSV that I want to import? I don't want to do that, because i get the CSV like this from the distributer. So I'm looking for a way to set default values, or modify the import array right before import via a hook or custom adapter.